# How to do a nested CoreData query?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following CoreData model: [Phone] <<--->> [Forwarding] <--->> [Number].

How do I build up a query that fetches a list of unique Numbers that are used by a Phone (so indirectly via its Forwardings)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a fetch request on the "Number" entity and add the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat@"ANY forwarding.phones == %@", thePhone]
```

to the fetch request (assuming that the to-one relationship from "Number" to
"Forwarding" is called "forwarding", and the to-many relationship from
"Forwarding" to "Phone" is called "phones").

Comment: Wow, that's amazingly simple; thanks! Do you know a good reference/book to learn about stuff like this?

Comment: @meaning-matters: You could start with the "Predicate Programming Guide", in particular https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html.